Ng-19 [ERROR] No matching export in "src/main.server.ts" for import "default"
I am trying to update my application from 18 to 19. I am facing this issue.

I added
export default AppServerModule

After that i am receiving vite related issue

main.server.ts
import '@angular/platform-server/init';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppServerModule } from 'main.server';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';

package.json
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^19.0.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.697.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "^3.697.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.697.0",
    "@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt": "^3.696.0",
    "@aws-sdk/util-user-agent-node": "^3.696.0",
    "@calumk/editorjs-columns": "^0.3.2",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.26",
    "@editorjs/attaches": "^1.3.0",
    "@editorjs/checklist": "^1.6.0",
    "@editorjs/code": "^2.9.3",
    "@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.30.7",
    "@editorjs/embed": "^2.7.6",
    "@editorjs/header": "^2.8.8",
    "@editorjs/image": "^2.10.0",
    "@editorjs/link": "^2.6.2",
    "@editorjs/list": "^2.0.2",
    "@editorjs/paragraph": "^2.11.6",
    "@editorjs/quote": "^2.7.2",
    "@editorjs/raw": "^2.5.0",
    "@editorjs/table": "^2.4.2",
    "@editorjs/underline": "^1.2.1",
    "@editorjs/warning": "^1.4.0",
    "@formio/angular": "^7.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.7.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/moment": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/rrule": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.15",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@pdftron/webviewer": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/stripe": "^8.0.417",
    "algoliasearch": "^5.15.0",
    "angular-instantsearch": "^4.4.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.8.3",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "apexcharts": "^4.0.0",
    "archiver": "^7.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.1",
    "crypto-es": "^2.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "domino-ext": "^2.1.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "editorjs-alert": "^1.1.4",
    "editorjs-html": "^3.4.3",
    "editorjs-style": "^3.0.3",
    "editorjs-text-color-plugin": "^2.0.4",
    "editorjs-toggle-block": "^0.3.16",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "firebase": "^11.0.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
    "gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
    "highlight.js": "11.10.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.2",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "instantsearch.js": "^4.75.5",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.2",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.8.4",
    "leader-line": "^1.0.7",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "material-steppers": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.13.0",
    "ng-quill": "^4.5.3",
    "ng-starrating": "^1.0.20",
    "ng-stripe-checkout": "^1.0.4",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^18.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "^15.0.1",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^22.0.0-alpha.10",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^7.0.8",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "npm": "^10.9.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.6",
    "pm2": "^5.4.3",
    "quill": "2.0.2",
    "quill-emoji": "^0.2.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "rrule": "2.8.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.3",
    "split-file": "^2.3.0",
    "stripe": "^17.4.0",
    "stripe-angular": "^1.9.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.14.5",
    "title-editorjs": "^1.0.2",
    "ts-md5": "^1.3.1",
    "tslib": "2.8.1",
    "video.js": "^8.19.1",
    "videojs-logo": "^3.0.0",
    "videojs-markers": "^1.0.1",
    "videojs-playlist": "^5.2.0",
    "videojs-seek-buttons": "^3.0.1",
    "vis": "^4.21.0-EOL",
    "vis-data": "^7.1.9",
    "vis-network": "^9.1.9",
    "vjs": "^0.1.8",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "19.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "19.0.0",
    "@formio/js": "^5.0.0-rc.48",
    "@ngx-builders/analyze": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "4.2.2",
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/highlight.js": "10.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "5.1.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.13",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.12",
    "@types/node": "22.9.1",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.3",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "formiojs": "^4.21.5",
    "jasmine-core": "5.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "6.4.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^18.0.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^18.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-quill": "^27.0.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.15",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "5.6.3",
    "utf-8-validate": "^6.0.5",
    "ws": "^8.18.0",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.1"
  }
}


main.ts
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import 'zone.js'
import 'firebase/analytics';

if ( environment.production )
{
    enableProdMode();
}


     platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,{
        ngZoneEventCoalescing: true,
     })
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
 


app.routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule,ExtraOptions } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: ComponentName, 
    loadChildren: () => import('./path/mod.module').then(m => m.ModModule)
  }
  
];
const options: ExtraOptions = {
  preloadingStrategy: MyPreloadingStrategyService,
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' ,
  initialNavigation : 'enabledBlocking',
  onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, options)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


my app.module.ts
@NgModule({ declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    exports: [],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ], imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
        provideAuth(() => {
            if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
                return initializeAuth(getApp(), {
                    persistence: browserLocalPersistence,
                    popupRedirectResolver: browserPopupRedirectResolver,
                });
            }
            return getAuth(getApp());
        }),
        StripeModule.forRoot(environment.stripe.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY),
        MetaModule.forRoot(),
        ...modules], providers: [...,
            
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptorService, multi: true },
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    ] })
export class AppModule {
    
}



Could you try the below configuration for main.ts and main.server.ts.
I created a new project to get the latest proper configuration, the same should be set and can solve your issue. Do commit/stash your changes before making this change so that you can rollback, if failed.

Modular:
main.server.ts
export { AppServerModule as default } from './app/app.module.server';

main.ts
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  ngZoneEventCoalescing: true,
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Stackblitz Demo -> cd test-modular -> npm i -> npm run start

Standalone:
main.server.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { config } from './app/app.config.server';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

if ((environment as any).production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, config);

export default bootstrap;

main.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

if ((environment as any).production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

Stackblitz Demo -> cd test -> npm i -> npm run start

I do not have app.config.server and app.config

@Santosh updated for standalone, with stackblitz reference

I have many modules and very few standalone. Do I need to complete migrate to standalone to use angular 19 ?

@Santosh sorry I meant i updated my answer for modular and shared the main.ts files

After delete node modules and cache I am getting errors such as router-outlet is not a known element. any idea why its causing issue ?

@Santosh sorry for late reply, did you change any of the component to standalone, that might have caused this issue. It's better to stick to modular main.ts if your code is majority modular

Its triggring app.component.ts router-outlet issue which is standalone false. I also updated main.ts file in my question at the bottom.

@Santhosh why do you need document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {  get rid of it angular never relies on JS like this, try deleting the .angular folder. also make sure appmodule.ts has the RouterModule in the imports, or the exports of approuting.module.ts

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
